# Is there Any Possibility to show Alert Using C# code Inside the ASPxGridview Events

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Code i written but Not showing alert :

```
protected void gvRole_RowInserted(objectsender,DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception == null)
    {
        //I dont want like this 
        //((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpInsertedRole"] = "New Role Inserted";
        //I want Like

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('New Role Inserted ');",true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for JSProperties in call back end client script handler and generate alert based on JSProperties in that method.

```
<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="HandleGridCallBackEnd" />

function HandleCallBackEnd(s, e) {

        var grid = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("ASPxGridView");
        if (grid != undefined) {
            if (grid.cpInsertedRole!= undefined
                && grid.cpInsertedRole.length > 0) {
                alert(grid.cpInsertedRole);
                grid.cpInsertedRole= '';
            }
        }
```

You can register javascript from C# as well if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. i done through JS property method but I want to Display using C # code

Comment: Even if you are writing C# code, you are registering JS client script only. Same way you can specify CallBackEnd handler and register code for that method in C#.

Comment: please provide markup for your grid client script functions.

Comment: did not getting how to do please provide some sample code

Comment: I don't want using JS properties. please explain using c# code

Answer (score 0):

Using Java script I'm getting alert but using C# Not Getting

```
<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s, e) {    
    if(typeof(gvAppUser.cpInsertedRole) != 'undefined')
    {
    alert(gvAppUser.cpInsertedRole);
    delete gvAppUser.cpInsertedRole;
    }
    }" />
```